# regular expression oracle sql

Tags: sql, regex, xml, oracle, regexp-substr

I have a table of people which build from two columns the first one is id and the second one is XML which counties the person details. 
For example the person XML file can be:

```
<Person>
    <name>First Last</name>
    <address>5 Champ de Mars</address>
    <city>Paris</city>
    <country>France</country>
    <phone-number>+3312345</phone-number>
</Person>
```

I would like to know how I can extract the value of each one of the parameters in the XML using `regexp_substr`, I have tried to use the function `EXTRACTVALUE` which caused me too many problems.
I am ruining oracle.
For example if querying the XML I gave:
`select regexp_substr(XML_file, 'pattern name') from peoples where id = 1;`
will result in: `First Last.`

Thank you in advance
Yonatan

Answer (score 2):

What kind of problems did you run into with EXTRACTVALUE?

Because it seems to be what you need...

Something along the lines of `SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(my_xml_column, '/Person/name') FROM my_table WHERE id=;` should return `'First Last'` as asked...